# What's a good source for handling images with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to know the simplest way of handling image upload, image storage in the database, and image display from the database in the context of Ruby on Rails. These images are for profile pictures. Any gems or plugins to simplify this process would be appreciated. Also, I'd like to know if `blob` is the data type for images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a look at paperclip. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip